# How to get python dictionary as an object with snmp OID as key

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm trying to pass a dictionary which has key as SNMP OID and value as dictionary with some values:

```
d = {'1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1': {'text':"something","help":'somethingelse','param':1},
     '1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.2':{'text':"something for this oid","help":'somethingelse_for this','param':2} ,
     and so on for other 1000 snmp OIDs }
```

Now I want to pass this dictionary to a class to convert it to dictionary object and get the details

```
class Struct(object):
def __init__(self, adict):
    """Convert a dictionary to a class

    @param :adict Dictionary
    """
    self.__dict__.update(adict)
    for k, v in adict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            self.__dict__[k] = Struct(v)


s = Struct(d)
s.? (what should be given here)
```

what should replace the ? as its a OID and I cannot give in quotes ("") as I need to pass attributes?
I get Invalid syntax error if I pass

```
s.'1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1'
or
s.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1
```

Also say, somehow after passing the oid attribute for example s.some_oid I would get an dictionary object, but I want it to return the value of that OID as well as dictionary object. Is it possible to do it?

meaning if I pass s.some_oid I should get

```
{'text':"something","help":'somethingelse','param':1}
```

and also a dictionary object which when used s.some_oid_text I should get

```
something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined the **getitem** function for your class. Once you define it, you can use the struct object as any ordinary dictionary. Also, to get the items inside as a Dictionary object you also need to create a function in the Struct class itself. For your reference, I have created the function 'itemsAsDict()'.

```
d = {'1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1':{'text':"something","help":'somethingelse','param':1}}

class Struct(object):

    def __init__(self, adict):
        """Convert a dictionary to a class

        @param :adict Dictionary
        """

        self.__dict__.update(adict)

        for k, v in adict.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                self.__dict__[k] = Struct(v)

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.__dict__[key]

    def values(self):
        return self.__dict__.values()

    def itemsAsDict(self):
        return dict(self.__dict__.items())


s = Struct(d)


#Get the dictionary at OID
print s['1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1'].itemsAsDict()
##Output : {'text': 'something', 'help': 'somethingelse', 'param': 1}

#Get the exact text
print s['1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1']['text']
###Output : something
```